# Magic date with regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to check wheter a date is magic or not via regex in Java. A date is a magic date if it has the same day,month and year(excluding the century).

```
            String magicDate ="12-12-2012";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{2})-\\d{2}-\\d{4}");
    //Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{2})-\\1-\\d{2}\\1");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(magicDate);

    if(matcher.matches())
    {
        System.out.println("Given date is a magic date");
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Match failed");
    }
```

Comment: Yes, thats how u verify that date,month and year are same.

Comment: Did you just edit the question to make it a different question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Szymon has the correct answer to your original question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23620785/438154) Basically, the javadoc of [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) states

> **Back references**
>
> `\n`  Whatever the `nth` capturing group matched

You have to use that instead of `$` to reference matched capturing groups.

To answer your edit, the javadoc of [`replaceFirst`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) states

> Note that backslashes (`\`) and dollar signs (`$`) in the replacement
>   string may cause the results to be different than if it were being
>   treated as a literal replacement string; see
>   `java.util.regex.Matcher#replaceFirst`. Use
>   `java.util.regex.Matcher#quoteReplacement` to suppress the special
>   meaning of these characters, if desired.

Comment: Hehe, I was just reading the same part of the doc, came back here and here it is :)

Comment: Thank you guys, I had made the same guess that the  difference is due to differenct classes.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `\1` to refer to your first group. Your regex is then:

```
(\d{2})-\1-\d{2}\1
```

In Java code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{2})-\\1-\\d{2}\\1");
```

Comment: @user1107888 What gives you that impression? The javadoc shows `\n`, where `n` is the captured group.

Comment: Check for instance this basic tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html. They use \1 and don't mention $1.

Comment: Scala uses triple quotes to ease backslash pain. `"""(\d{2})-\1-\d{2}\1""".r`

Comment: @som-snytt What does Scala has to do with the question?

Comment: Just a plug.  "But wait, there's more!"

Comment: @Szymon what about when it's the year 10-10-10010 ?  Or back in 2-2-202 ?

Comment: @mrres1 And what about BC years? I don't think the question was really about the proper regex for all occasions but about referencing groups within regex.

Comment: @Szymon Sure it is.  6-6-666, or 10-10-1010.  Those are dates he is talking about.

Answer (score -1):

Capture the first group, 1 or 2 digits, use `\1` to refer to it:

```
(\d{1,2})-\1-\d{0,}\1
```

Result:

```
8-8-2008           match
09-09-2009         match
10-10-2002         no match
11-11-2011         match
12-12-2012         match
```

It will also work for past dates and future:

```
6-6-6              match
6-6-666            match

1-1-99991          match
5-5-1000000005     match
```